# PHP formulate path from URL

Tags: php, mysql, uri

Using .htaccess all addresses are rewritten to index.php

Index.php needs to then work out which file to include. At the moment it explodes on the '/' and performs a foreach to work out which file. This is causing errors.

First we get the URI.

If there is one address eg. `localhost/next-page` then we want to include a file with that name and the extension PHP `include('content/'.$post.'.php');` and give global variables for `$table` as `'PAGES'` and `$post` as `'next-page'`

If there are two then the first should be considered the $table and the second the $post, and the file to include should be `include('content/single-'.$post.'.php');`

How do we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [isolate the relevant part of the URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) (in this case that's probably the path, although without your rewrite rule we don't know). Then:

```
$parts = explode('/', $path);
switch(count($parts)) {
    case 1:
        // set your globals (why are you using globals????)
        include('content/'.$parts[0].'.php');
        break;
    case 2:
        // do whatever you need with $parts[0] and $parts[1]
        break;
    // etc
}
```

If there's significant similarity between some cases, you can allow a fall-through from one case to the next after doing some preliminary work to normalize the situation, e.g.

```
    case 1:
        array_unshift($parts, 'PAGES'); // now $parts will have two elements
        // intentional fall-through
    case 2:
        // do whatever you need with $parts[0] and $parts[1]
        break;
```

Finally: if there's lots of stuff you need to do with the items inside `$parts`, you can give them names to make the code more readable using the [`list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct:

```
    case 2:
        list($table, $post) = $parts;
        // carry on as before but now $table == $parts[0] and $post == $parts[1]
```